# Internal build system error. BuildProgram exited with code 137 - Unity Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have just formatted my iMac with Ventura 13.4 and installed latest version of Unity Editor 2021.3.25f1.
As I opened my project I was started getting this error:
[image]

Also Unity Editor is opened in the Safe Mode.
I don't know how to solve this error and my project stopped working.
If any person has some knowledge about this then please share with me because I got stuck with this from last few hours.

Comment: Do your scripts have build errors? I would try closing Unity, deleting the Library directory in your project, then opening it again and letting it reimport everything.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Okay I will delete Library folder and reopen project again so that all things reimported again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how but as I remove or add Test Framework through Package Manager, it's solving my problem.

I have confirmed this two times.
[image]

This is weird but working for me successfully.